# Trouble loading Qt UI (with images) from plugin (.so)

Tags: qt, plugins, qwidget

I have a plugin that loads and shows a custom widget that displays an image (as a background for a QLabel) loaded from a resource file (resources.qrc). The problem I'm facing is that once the plugin is loaded, it shows the widget properly, but not the image. I tried putting "Q_INIT_RESOURCE( resources )" everywhere, but nothing happens. I have created many custom widgets that use qrc files to display images, but only directly within an app, which have worked just fine. This time is from a plugin, so there must be something I'm missing here. Any help?

```
// TheInterface.h
class TheInterface
{
    ...
}
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(TheInterface,"com.system.subsystem.TheInterface/1.0");



// MyWidget.h
class MyWidget : public QWidget, public Ui::MyWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}



// MyPlugin.h
#include "TheInterface.h"
class MyPlugin : public QOBject,
                 public TheInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(TheInterface)

    ...
};

// MyPlugin.cpp
#include "MyPlugin.h"
#include "MyWidget.h"
MyPlugin::MyPlugin()
{
    MyPlugin* w = new MyPlugin();
    w->show();
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(myplugin, MyPlugin)
```

Comment: related: [How to intialize Qt resources from a shared library ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319792/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem was that the main application had already a qrc file with the same name (`resources.qrc`). The plugin --being loaded by the main app-- has a different `resources.qrc` file, but because the main app had one already with the same name, it was not loading it. I changed the name of the resource file in the plugin and worked perfectly. Of course, I had to change the `Q_INIT_RESOURCE( resources );` to `Q_INIT_RESOURCE( new_resource_file_basename );` which was called from the constructor of the `MyWidget` class (`MyWidget::MyWidget()`). In other words, it does NOT need to be in the constructor of the plugin (`MyPlugin::MyPlugin()`). It makes sense, since the `MyWidget` class is the one using the resource file, not the plugin.